# Jquery show only current parent childrens. Hide another families

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Have 3 level menu:

```js
jQuery("#product_cats_nav li").toggle(
    function () {
        //var current = jQuery(this).closest('.level1');
        //jQuery(current).siblings().addClass("hide");
        jQuery(this).children().removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
    },
    function () {
        jQuery(this).find("ul").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    }
);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
};

.show {
  display: block
};


#top_menu ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: lime ;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#top_menu li {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-full" id="top_menu">
    <ul id="product_cats_nav">
        <li class="level1" menu-level="1">Level1 A
            <ul class="hide">
                <li class="level2" menu-level="2">Level2 A
                    <ul class="hide">
                        <li class="level3" menu-level="3">
                            <a  href="#">Level3 A</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="level1" menu-level="1">Level1 B
            <ul class="hide">
                <li class="level2" menu-level="2">Level2 B
                    <ul class="hide">
                        <li class="level3" menu-level="3">
                            <a  href="#">Level3 B</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**Goal:**
When some submenu(level2) or (level1) is clicked and active (opened) close all another level1 childrens. 
Current js just toogle one block with another, but not hide elements of another level1 children fammily
In snippet i had comment out my triyings with sibling..
How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
jQuery("#product_cats_nav li").toggle(
    function () {
        //var current = jQuery(this).closest('.level1');
        //jQuery(current).siblings().addClass("hide");
        jQuery(this).closest('#product_cats_nav').find('ul').removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
        jQuery(this).children().removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
        
    },
    function () {
        jQuery(this).find("ul").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    }
);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
};

.show {
  display: block
};


#top_menu ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: lime ;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#top_menu li {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-full" id="top_menu">
    <ul id="product_cats_nav">
        <li class="level1" menu-level="1">Level1 A
            <ul class="hide">
                <li class="level2" menu-level="2">Level2 A
                    <ul class="hide">
                        <li class="level3" menu-level="3">
                            <a  href="#">Level3 A</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="level1" menu-level="1">Level1 B
            <ul class="hide">
                <li class="level2" menu-level="2">Level2 B
                    <ul class="hide">
                        <li class="level3" menu-level="3">
                            <a  href="#">Level3 B</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Jeah, but current example works (show, handles) only two levels. 3rd level is missing